# How to keep app language setting after device restart?

Tags: android, locale, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

My app has a language setting feature. Now it works perfectly, but after I restart the device, the language reverts to the original setting.

Does anyone have any ideas? Do i need to implement `SharedPreferences`?

---

I got the answer. If you have Language setting inside your app. and after restart device the last language you've changed still be default. One of the way to make this work, to store variable   through `SharedPreferences` ; might be *String language*.

Another thing, you need to have is initiate class. so that, whenever you open app. it able to call.

For example

`Setting appSettings = Setting.getInstance(getApplicationContext());`

`language = appSetting.getLanguage();`

`appSetting.setLanguage(language);`

Comment: ya you need to store the options for language while chosen by user.

Comment: Thanks all you guy i will try all of your advises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the best option is to use SharedPreferences.

You can find a tutorial here: http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=1731

Hope this helps...

Comment: thanks you for you help, but i think event we change it by using SharedPreferences, The Whole application still not change .. just some activity i guess,is't it? according to FunkTheMonk

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, you should use a SharedPreferences variable to store active language.

Comment: Have you try it? for language.. i try but it's not work, i don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

Unless they've changed things, changing locale on a per-activity basis is a bad idea. Instead you should start the device's language setting activity via an intent using [this action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS)

Comment: seem like this might be the better way to change language, Just.. wonder there is no way to update application language in code really?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `SharedPreferences`, but rather the `android:configChanges="locale"` [attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) in your manifest. If you change the current Locale then the activity will remember it for you.

Comment: i try this, but after restart the device the device, app language still use "ENGLISH" which is the default language of this device. By the way, i declare android:configChanges="locale" inside Application tag: <Application android:configChanges="locale" > , Am i right?

Comment: No it's an activity attribute (I don't know why) : `<activity android:configChanges="locale ...>" `